# How can I prove that $T(n)=\sqrt{n}T(\sqrt{n})+n$ grows as $\Theta(n\log \log{n})$?

Tags: complexity-theory, recursion

How can I prove that if $T(n) = \sqrt{n}T(\sqrt{n}) + n$ then $T(n) = \Theta(n\log\log n)$?

I tried to define $T(n)$ by $G(n)$, prove about $G(n)$, and then to return to $T(n)$, but it's not working..

Comment: Start by dividing both sides of the recurrence by $n$ to get $\frac{T(n)}{n}=\frac{T(\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n}}+1$. Write $\frac{T(n)}{n}=F(n)$. Now you have a much easier recurrence to work with:  $F(n)=F(\sqrt{n})+1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use repeated substitution:
$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= n + \sqrt{n}T(\sqrt{n}) \\ &=
n + n + n^{3/4} T(n^{1/4}) \\ &=
n + n + n + n^{7/8} T(n^{1/8}) \\ &= \cdots
\end{align*}
$$
You reach the base case after after $\ell$ iterations when $n^{1/2^\ell} = 2$ (say), whose solution is $\ell = \log_2\log_2 n$. Assuming for simplicity that $T(2) = 0$, we get $T(n) = n\log_2 \log_2 n$.